# Animate CollectionViewCell after deleting item

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, delegates, uicollectionviewcell

For my `CollectionView` I have this `animation` inside `willDisplay` :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        // Add animations here
        let animation = AnimationFactory.makeMoveUpWithFade(rowHeight: cell.frame.height, duration: 0.5, delayFactor: 0.1)
        let animator = Animator(animation: animation)
        animator.animate(cell: cell, at: indexPath, in: collectionView)

}
```

[This](https://www.vadimbulavin.com/tableviewcell-display-animation/) is how the animation works (I implemented it for `CollectionView`)  if you need it for more info.

**Probelm:**

Inside my project the user can `create` and `delete` an `item`.

Right now the `collectionView` is not animating after `deleting` even though I am calling `reloadData`:

```
extension MainViewController: DismissWishlistDelegate {

func dismissWishlistVC(dataArray: [Wishlist], dropDownArray: [DropDownOption]) {
    self.dataSourceArray = dataArray
    self.dropOptions = dropDownArray
    self.makeWishView.dropDownButton.dropView.tableView.reloadData()

    // reload the collection view
    theCollectionView.reloadData()
    theCollectionView.performBatchUpdates(nil, completion: nil)

}
}
```

This is where I call the `delegate` inside my other `ViewController`:

```
func deleteTapped(){

    let alertcontroller = UIAlertController(title: "Wishlist löschen", message: "Sicher, dass du diese Wishlist löschen möchtest?", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Löschen", style: .default) { (alert) in

        DataHandler.deleteWishlist(self.wishList.index)

        self.dataSourceArray.remove(at: self.currentWishListIDX)
        self.dropOptions.remove(at: self.currentWishListIDX)

        // change heroID so wishlist image doesnt animate
        self.wishlistImage.heroID = "delete"

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        //  update datasource array in MainVC
        self.dismissWishlistDelegate?.dismissWishlistVC(dataArray: self.dataSourceArray, dropDownArray: self.dropOptions)

    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Abbrechen", style: .default) { (alert) in
        print("abbrechen")
    }


    alertcontroller.addAction(cancelAction)
    alertcontroller.addAction(deleteAction)

    self.present(alertcontroller, animated: true)
}
```

When `creating` the animation works just fine. This is how my `createDelegateFunction` looks like this:

```
func createListTappedDelegate(listImage: UIImage, listImageIndex: Int, listName: String) {
    // append created list to data source array
    var textColor = UIColor.white
    if Constants.Wishlist.darkTextColorIndexes.contains(listImageIndex) {
        textColor = UIColor.darkGray
    }

    let newIndex = self.dataSourceArray.last!.index + 1

    self.dataSourceArray.append(Wishlist(name: listName, image: listImage, wishData: [Wish](), color: Constants.Wishlist.customColors[listImageIndex], textColor: textColor, index: newIndex))

    // append created list to drop down options
    self.dropOptions.append(DropDownOption(name: listName, image: listImage))

    // reload the collection view
    theCollectionView.reloadData()
    theCollectionView.performBatchUpdates(nil, completion: {
        (result) in
        // scroll to make newly added row visible (if needed)
        let i = self.theCollectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) - 1
        let idx = IndexPath(item: i, section: 0)
        self.theCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: idx, at: .bottom, animated: true)

    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Animation of `IUCollectionView` elements insertion and deletion is correctly done using [`finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItem(at:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617740-finallayoutattributesfordisappea) and [initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItem(at:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617789-initiallayoutattributesforappear)

Little excerpt from Apple's documentation on `finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItem(at:)`

> This method is called after the prepare(forCollectionViewUpdates:) method and before the finalizeCollectionViewUpdates() method for any items that are about to be deleted. Your implementation should return the layout information that describes the final position and state of the item. The collection view uses this information as the end point for any animations. (The starting point of the animation is the item’s current location.) If you return nil, the layout object uses the same attributes for both the start and end points of the animation.

Comment: @Chris, Good explanation provided at Objc.io blog (Article samples are in Objective C, but apis didn't change much since then): https://www.objc.io/issues/12-animations/collectionview-animations/

Comment: @Chris, CollectionView is heavily depending on the Layout. Performing animations affecting layout without Layout change is potentially error prone and may lead to visual bugs. This is my point of view. If you wish, you can use your approach, ofc.

Comment: thanks for the answer and explanation! But for now I think I will stick with my way, never had any issues. Do you have an idea on how to fix the actual problem?

Comment: what I would like to have is some function I can call from anywhere that `reloads` the `collectionView` with the `animation`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by removing `performBatchUpdates` ... I have no idea why it works now and what exactly `performBatchUpdates` does but it works so if anyone wants to explain it to me, feel free :D

The final function looks like this:

```
func dismissWishlistVC(dataArray: [Wishlist], dropDownArray: [DropDownOption], shouldDeleteWithAnimation: Bool, indexToDelete: Int) {

    if shouldDeleteWithAnimation {

        self.shouldAnimateCells = true
        self.dataSourceArray.remove(at: self.currentWishListIDX)
        self.dropOptions.remove(at: self.currentWishListIDX)

        // reload the collection view
        theCollectionView.reloadData()


    } else {

        self.shouldAnimateCells = false
        self.dataSourceArray = dataArray
        self.dropOptions = dropDownArray

        // reload the collection view
        theCollectionView.reloadData()
        theCollectionView.performBatchUpdates(nil, completion: nil)
    }

    self.makeWishView.dropDownButton.dropView.tableView.reloadData()

}
```